# Trigger multiple CI executions for each applicable rule

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CI configurations which look like this:

```
.rule_template: &rule_configuration
  rules:
    - changes:
        - file/dev/script1.txt
      variables:
        FILE: file/dev/script1.txt
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost1
    - changes:
        - file/test/script1.txt
      variables:
        FILE: file/test/script1.txt
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost2
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'

default:
  tags:
    - scripts

stages:
  - copy

COPY scripts 1/6:
  <<: *rule_configuration
  stage: copy
  script: |
    cp $FILE $DESTINATION_HOST:/
    
....
```

This is fine when there is a change to 1 file either  `dev/script1.txt` or  `test/script1.txt`. But an MR can contain changes to both files also, in which case both needs to be copied. However CI runs on once for one file (not sure which sequence it picks).

How can I design the CI for my requirements and trigger difference CI executions for each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the **first match**. so only create one job.

you can change your .gitlab-ci.yml look like this [sample code](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/556018361):

```yaml
.script_template:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  stage: copy
  script:
    - echo "CP from $FILE to $DESTINATION_HOST"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - $FILE

stages:
  - copy

script 1 file changes:
  extends: .script_template
  variables:
    FILE: script1.txt
    DESTINATION_HOST: somehost1

script 2 file changes:
  extends: .script_template
  variables:
    FILE: script2.txt
    DESTINATION_HOST: somehost2
```

Reference:

- [`.gitlab-ci.yml` keyword reference | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)